# What is your experience with Microtech Gelfell microphones?

Tags: microphone, recommendations, purchase-advice

I have an opportunity to get the Microtech Gelfell sms 2000 preamp with the M series of diaphragms for quite a good price. Haven't had much luck on the net regarding feedback or reviews.

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with them and how they worked for you?

I seems that from what I have read that it is mainly used in the music industry.

Answer (score 2):

Hi,

I've worked with a pair of them only once, don't remember which exact type. They're really nice though and unfortunately really expensive also.
I don't know which types you are interested in, but I tend to buy mic's I know a lot about already (soundwise), especially if they're that expensive. Best question to ask yourselve is, why should i buy this microphone and not any other? Do i really need this exact model?
I mean, I can imagine the secondhand price is alluring, but do you really need those exact models and do they fit your purpose?

Good luck on your decision!

Comment: @ Arnoud. Thanks for the response. I too research a product before buying it. It is crucial that you know what it is that you are buying, what experiences others have had with that product and how compatible it is within the industry. 